# How to open a StreamReader in ShareDenyWrite mode?

Tags: c#, streamreader, sharing, fileshare, textreader

How do i open a [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) with [`FILE_SHARE_READ`, `FILE_SHARE_WRITE`, `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

---

### Same question, slightly expanded

How do i open a `StreamReader` so that i can read an encoded text file, with sharing options so that another process can read the file?

How do i open a `StreamReader` so that i can read an encoded text file, with sharing options so that another process can modify the file while i'm reading it?

How do i open a `StreamReader` so that i can read an encoded text file, with sharing options so that another process can delete the file while i'm reading it?

---

### Same question, slightly more expanded

In the .NET Framework class library there is a class called `StreamReader`. It is the only class designed to read **"text"**, which is why it descends from the abstract base `TextReader` class. The `TextReader/StreamReader` allows you to specify the encoding used by the file you are trying to open, and can decode the file for you, returning `Strings` of text.

Once i've opened a file with the `StreamReader`:

```
var sr = new StreamReader(path);
```

The file is locked, with other processes unable to *modify* or *delete* the file. What i need is the equivalent of a [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh.aspx) class's [`FileShare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) enumeration:

- **None**: Declines sharing of the current file. Any request to open the file (by this process or another process) will fail until the file is closed.
- **Read**": Allows subsequent opening of the file for reading. If this flag is not specified, any request to open the file for reading (by this process or another process) will fail until the file is closed. However, even if this flag is specified, additional permissions might still be needed to access the file.
- **Write**: Allows subsequent opening of the file for writing. If this flag is not specified, any request to open the file for writing (by this process or another process) will fail until the file is closed. However, even if this flag is specified, additional permissions might still be needed to access the file.
- **ReadWrite**:Allows subsequent opening of the file for reading or writing. If this flag is not specified, any request to open the file for reading or writing (by this process or another process) will fail until the file is closed. However, even if this flag is specified, additional permissions might still be needed to access the file.
- **Delete**: Allows subsequent deleting of a file.

Except that, for obvious reasons, i cannot use a `FileStream` -  have to use a `StreamReader`.

How can i open a `StreamReader` with `FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`StreamReader` [has a constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at) that can take a stream.  So instead of using the constructor that takes a string path, first create a `FileStream` with the options that you want, then pass that `FileStream` to the `StreamReader` constructor.

Answer (score 7):

> How can i open a StreamReader with FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete ?

When you have solved the problem for a Stream, the Reader is easy:

```
var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileShare.ReadWrite|FileShare.Delete);
var sr = new StreamReader(fs);
```

And of course that should be wrapped in a `using() { }` block.

Comment: Sorry Henk, but Sean needs the rep more than you :)

Comment: At the C# 4.5 I see the usage as var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete);  namely they added another parameter between FileMode.Open and FileShare.ReadWrite, which is FileAccess..

Comment: @phoad - I don't think that is new, it has multiple overloads.

Comment: I mean I could not see a constructor with only FileShare parameter, they all want FileAccess parameter if FileShare is wanted to be used. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx